# ReportingService2005 via WCF - works with impersonation, but not with username/password

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, reporting-services, credentials

I'm hooking into SSRS 2008's ReportingService2005 service via WCF.

I have it working with impersonation, like this:

```
ReportingService2005SoapClient rService = 
    new ReportingService2005SoapClient("endpoint config name", "the url");
rService.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
    System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
rService.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
    CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

But when I try and pass a specific username/password to it instead, like this:

```
rService.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = 
    new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
```

I get this error on the first method call:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

Here's the relevant part of my wcf binding config:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ReportingService2005Soap"  ... blah blah blah ...
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

I'm confused by the error message mentioning Ntlm in two different cases.

So the question is - which of the two squillion different WCF settings do I need to fiddle with to get this to work?   : )

edit: here is the authentication bit from RSReportServer.config from the SSRS server:

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

and from the SSRS web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

edit: I'll mark the best answer so far for now, but this is still open because I havent yet found a solution that lets me set arbitrary credentials in code.

Comment: The error message suggests that this might simply be a casing problem - have you tried amending the binding to use `clientCredentialType="NTLM" proxyCredentialType="NTLM"`?

Comment: @Ed: Yeah, tried that. If I use capitals I get error 'The value of the property 'clientCredentialType' cannot be parsed.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK new try.

The WCF service runs in IIS, the SSRS uses windows authentication.

When you have windows authentication it works since the users windows security context is used.

When you use user name and password it is the IIS user, which is used. Which does not have access to SSRS.

So to get it to work:

- Set impersonate=false in the security section of the WCF services web.config.
- That will force it to use the identity of the application pool
- Then change the identity of the application pool to a user that has access to SSRS

Comment: Yes, I think it is set to windows authentication. I think it should still be possible to log onto it as a fixed user though (the ASP.NET ReportViewer component is able to do so, for example)

Comment: Come to think of it, SSRS 2008 doesn't use IIS.

Comment: Thanks, your application pool suggestion works. That solves my immediate problem, but suggests that I cannot set arbitrary credentials in code. That is, I only have the choice of either impersonation or application pool identities.

Comment: I'm not following you on the application pool suggestion. Since we're in SSRS and not IIS, we don't have an application pool. How were you able to set its identity if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

Got around it by specifying:

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change your transport element attribute values to:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
```

Hope that helps ...

Comment: I then get a slightly different error: "*The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'.*"

Comment: Are your client and SSRS server on the same domain or do the domains have a trust relationship?

Comment: Can you add: client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNTLM = True

Comment: :That didn't make any difference. Thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: I is so weird, handshake protocol is OK, but user authentication does not seem to be commenced. It this would have kicked-in I would expect to see another error message. Elementary, the question is: What is the difference between the cached credential on your system and explicitly creating a new one. That should not be rocket science. Though, it is not working for your case. May I propose to use Wireshark on the line and look at the handshake differences between the working and not working situation?

Comment: I am looking at it with Wireshark but its a bit of a learning curve. Shiraz answer suggests that with Windows authentication you can imprersonate or use the applciation pool account but not build any other credential - does that make sense?

Comment: Could make sense, can we have a documented link on that behavior?